# В R не читает таблицы из SQLite

Tags: sqlite, r, sqlite3, table, error404

Подскажите где ошибка. Я пытаюсь вытащить таблицы из SQLite в R. В начале он не читал БД, но потом открыл ее, но таблицы все равно не видит.

````
    ```> library('RSQLite')
    > require(SQLite)
    Loading required package: SQLite
    Warning message:
    In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
       there is no package called ‘SQLite’
   > drv <- dbDriver("SQLite") 
   > require('RSQLite')
   > dvr <- dbDriver('RSQLite')
   Error: Couldn't find driver RSQLite. Looked in:
   * global namespace
   * in package called RSQLite
   * in package called RRSQLite
   > View(drv)
   > con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname= 'test.db')
   > dbListTables(con)
   character(0)
   > dbReadTable(con, 'name')
   Error: no such table: name
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

пример из [документации](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/vignettes/RSQLite.html):

загружаем пакет `DBI`:

```
> library(DBI)
```

подключаемся к базе данных в файле `my-db.sqlite` (если файла не было — будет создан):

```
> mydb <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "my-db.sqlite")
```

записываем в него содержимое «штатных» таблиц `mtcars` и `iris` (под другими именами для наглядности — `mtcars2` и `iris2`):

```
> dbWriteTable(mydb, "mtcars2", mtcars)
> dbWriteTable(mydb, "iris2", iris)
```

отключаемся:

```
> dbDisconnect(mydb)
```

теперь проверка. подключаемся снова и выводим список таблиц:

```
> mydb <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "my-db.sqlite")
> dbListTables(mydb)
[1] "iris2"   "mtcars2"
```

ещё для наглядности — запрос к таблице:

```
> dbGetQuery(mydb, 'select * from iris2 limit 5')
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

всё на месте. не забываем отключиться:

```
> dbDisconnect(mydb)
```

---

ах, да. пример чтения таблицы в переменную:

```
> mydb <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "my-db.sqlite")
> копия.iris <- dbReadTable(mydb, "iris2")
> dbDisconnect(mydb)

> str(копия.iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : chr  "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" ...
```

Comment: '''> library("DBI", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/4.0")
> > mydb <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "my-db.sqlite")
Error: unexpected '>' in ">" '''

выдает это :(

Comment: `>` — это приглашение командной строки. не надо его копировать.